# Probability hitting a bottle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Each of Paula and David have two balls and shoot alternately on a bottle.
Paula hits with p = 1/3 and David hits with p = 1/4.

a) What is the probability that Paula will hit the bottle when she starts?

b) What is the probability that David will hit the bottle when Paula starts and throws twice?

$$$$

I have done the following:

a) Isn't the probability equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ ?

b) So, we want that Paula throws and fails, then David throws and fails, then Paula throws again and fails and at last David throws and hits the bottle, right?

So is the probability equal to $\left (1-\frac{1}{3}\right )\cdot \left (1-\frac{1}{4}\right )\cdot \left (1-\frac{1}{3}\right )\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: Since Paula starts and throws twice, I thought that the first time must be a failure and David has also to fail so that at the second try of Paula there will be a success. Am I thinking wrong? @mfl

Comment: you are absolutely right three are two cases when Paula starts and wins the game she hits in the first trial or she fails David fails then she hits the bottle

Comment: So are the probabilities that I calculated correct? @James

Comment: There is no further information. Do we have here a binomial distribution? Or would we have that just when we considered one of Paula or David? @mfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we assume that the bottle will  not be replaced. At **a)** there are two ways that Paula hits the bottle if she starts.

$P(\text{"Paula hits the bottle at her first shot"})=P(A)=\frac13$

Paula hits the bottle at her second shot. That means that Paula and David don't hit the bottle at their first shots. The probability is $\frac23\cdot \frac34$. And at the second shot of Paula the bottle has to be hit with the probability of $\frac13$. Therefore $P(\text{"Paula hits the bottle at her second shot"})=P(B)=\frac23\cdot \frac34\cdot \frac13=\frac{6}{36}=\frac1{6}$

Therefore $P(\text{"Paula hits the bottle"})=P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)=\frac13+\frac1{6}=\frac1{2}$

It is worth mention that $P(A\cap B)=0$

At **b)** the reasoning and the calculation is right.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You´re welcome.